# SSL Configuration for client subdomains

Tags: ssl, https, appharbor

Let's say I host an application with AppHarbor at 
abc.appharbor.com

With the main domain at:
www.abc.com

Through appharbor, I let people set up custom subdomains on their site:
clients.garysieling.com
clients.test.com
(etc - more added over time)

Is there a way to configure AppHarbor such that the subdomains all can have SSL?

Currently I have SNI SSL, and my customers get certificate errors if I enable SSL on the subdomains. I've looked at CloudFlare's SSL, but I'm concerned that would require me to manage a customer's entire DNS system.

I've had one customer offer to purchase his own SSL certificate, but since the configuration appears to be at AppHarbor's level, I think I'd have to deploy a new application (sharing the existing database), which currently appears to be the most feasible approach.

Comment: It's not about the configuration, more a matter of what's in the certificate, whether it allows a wildcard subdomain or not.

Comment: If the certificate allows *.mydomain.com, I'm not sure it helps, because people are actually going through something like client.theirdomain.com with a CNAME record to my subdomain.

Comment: CNAME will not help, HTTP redirect will not help etc. The certificate must match the hostname you have in the URL.